# Writing a Visual Studio extension for a custom designer

Tags: visual-studio, extensibility, visualdesigner

So, I've got something I want to try out.  The idea is to have a visual designer that works as a Visual Studio Extension, I want to be able to drag out event handlers and wire up behaviors, anyone who's ever played with the warcraft III script editor will have a pretty good idea what I'm wanting to do.  Is this kind of thing readily handled in the visual studio extensibility tools? If so where should I start looking to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's absolutely possible using the Visual Studio Extensibility tools.  You'll want to create  a VS Package.  There are a few different mechanisms (macros, add-ins, and packages)  you can use to extend Visual Studio, but Packages are by far the most powerful.  More specifically, you should look into [creating a "Custom Editor/Designer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166329.aspx).

You'll need to download the Visual Studio 2010 SDK if you haven't already.  There's a fantastic wizard for creating new VS Packages which will even generate a sample "Custom editor" that you can use as a starting point for your custom designer.  I'd recommend reading through the code that the wizard generates until you really understand it.  There's a *lot* of stuff going on, so it can take a while.  If you want a book to get started, pretty much the only one I've found is [Professional Visual Studio Extensibility](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470230843), but there are other good resources on the internet.  A few I've used are [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/vextend.aspx) and [DiveDeeper's VSX blog](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/default.aspx).  Probably the best way to get started is reading the [code samples from the VSX team](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx), they even have about 10-15 samples related to custom editors!

Good luck!