# Extend Visual Studio to wrap around an external provider

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I want to write a visual studio extension to build a wrapper around a technology outside of .Net. Essentially I am looking to create functionality similar to the "Service Reference" where the user will specify a resource and my extension will build a .Net wrapper around that resource.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178022/writing-a-visual-studio-extension-for-a-custom-designer) which references the article [Create custom editors and designers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-editors-and-designers?view=vs-2019). The article explains editors but despite its name barely mentions designers and never really distinguishes the two.

Also, the article has a line that makes me think that writing an editor may not be what I need,

> Note, however, that users will not be able to use a custom editor to
>   edit standard Visual Studio projects.

So, in order to make a custom editor I have to make my own project type? What if I want my extension to be usable in any project type?

I would appreciate any direction that can be provided. I have extensive .Net experience, but am new to writing VS Extensions. I am building in visual Studio 2019 RC.

Comment: Hi, so which way you want to open your custom option? Right-click in the editor and choose "xxx option"? What about  setting the option at menu command or one button in solution explorer?

Comment: I guess I am open to any of those possibilities. I think Ideal would be creating it with an "Add..." and then being able to configure/refresh it with a context menu in the solution explorer.

Comment: You may get some help from this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967027/vsix-project-context-menu) which gives the suggestion about how to put function button under Add-node in solution explorer.

Comment: That is valuable information that I will make use of. However, my question here is more basic. I need to know for sure what an editor is and what a designer is and which I need to create (or do I need something else?). I don't want to build out my extension and then discover that it only works on a custom project type.

Comment: An editor is like the window where we use to write code. For the designer, it might be something like a designer in winform , wpf.(But I'm not familiar with it)

Comment: As what you want to develop is an function like add=> service ref, I think you don't need to use editor or designer, the more suitable way can be what I provide above. And for sth in solution explorer, I think it can works no matter in default project type or custom ones.(For this, I will try it this weekend if possible, update I will share here)